# Is it possible to trust a certificate in a webpage context?

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I have a website, let's say `example.com`.
I have a SSL Certificate for `example.com` but not `*.example.com`.
I want to do `api.example.com` but I can only make a self-signed certificate for that domain.

Is it possible to do something like this:
When I access `example.com`, it loads a root certificate from the same domain over HTTPS with a valid certificate (ex. `https://example.com/cert/root.pem`) and then mark the certificate as trusted for this particular webpage.
In a sense, I am provisioning a new certificate from a valid SSL certificate, but it should not be a problem as long as the trust is only applied for this particular webpage right?

Comment: No, this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I asked this question and I an answering it because I have found a workaround.

I can put a NGINX reverse proxy under `example.com` and redirect traffic to different sub-servers, practically secures all page with SSL.

Although `app.example.com` would still not be trusted because domain is not given to the server during SSL handshake+I don't have a certificate for it, I can just put the site under `example.com/app`.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible to do it.

Comment: Please provide more information to substantiate your claim.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel If this is possible, that is a big security breach! Also, it will be a good option for a hacker to pretend trusted if this is possible!

Comment: And if there a solution, why we need to buy a certificate up to $210/year from a trusted CA i.e. Sectigo? Everyone can trust his CA internationally and who looks for a true-certified trusted CA? That's the difference between self-signed and trusted, you can't change this logic anyway!

Comment: My comment was posted from the review queue: answers saying something isn't possible need to substantiate and explain why it isn't possible, not just say it isn't possible. I wasn't talking about the specifics of the question or claiming that what the OP is asking is possible, just that you should improve your answer.